# Texts with iPhone and iCloud

Tags: icloud, messages

Will a text that is stored in iCloud get deleted from iCloud when you delete it from your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

For practical purposes, texts aren't really "stored" in iCloud. I say that with two caveats. First, Apple may store them for their own use and second, they may be stored through your iOS device's iCloud backup.

As such, when you delete a message off of your iOS device, that change doesn't populate to other devices, and it isn't deleted from iCloud *until* your device backs up itself to iCloud (likely over night). The message will be deleted only from your device unless the backup occurs.

Comment: @D.B If an answer has solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left.